# $\frac{1}{1-\frac{z^{b}}{a}}=\sum \left ( \frac{z^{b}}{a} \right )^{n} \; \; \; \; \; \; \left | z \right |<\sqrt[b]{a}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I have a doubt on Taylor's series. I always used the formula:

$$\frac{1}{1-\frac{z}{a}}=\sum \left ( \frac{z}{a} \right )^{n}  \; \; \; \; \; \;   \left | z \right |<a$$

Is it always true also the following

$$\frac{1}{1-\frac{z^{b}}{a}}=\sum \left ( \frac{z^{b}}{a} \right )^{n}  \; \; \; \; \; \;   \left | z \right |<\sqrt[b]{a}$$

Thank you so much.

Comment: I'm so sorry I made a mistake of distraction.

Comment: Your conclusion is true if $b$ is positive. We tend to not use the notation $\sqrt[b]{a}$ when $b<0$, but if you wanted to include that case, it is not true then.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:
$$\frac{1}{1-\frac{z^{b}}{a}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left ( \frac{z^{b}}{a} \right )^{n}  \; \; \; \; \; \;   \left | z \right |<\sqrt[b]{a}$$
holds for **positive** $b\in \mathbf R$ since we have
$$\left| \frac{z^b}{a} \right| < 1 \qquad \Longleftrightarrow \qquad |z| < \sqrt[b]{a}.$$

Comment: Only as long as `a > 0`. `a < 0` implies `z^b > 1`

Comment: Of course is $a>0$.